# Set Vaadin default browser as Chrome

Tags: eclipse, browser, vaadin

How to open the Vaadin project in browsers like chrome, safari rather than Eclipse's default browser, when we run/debug a Vaadin project?

I really need it for my project to avoid creating multiple instance for a class when I again open the Vaadin app in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the browser from eclipse, you have to go in eclipse to "Preferences" -> "General" -> "Web Browser". There you can change the Browser what eclipse is using.